# Обновление данных joomla

Tags: joomla, mysql

Tсть таблица, в которой >360 записей, которые были перенесены из `virtuemart`. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было обновить значение картинок для таблицы, чтоб в ручную не вставлять каждую.

Нашел таблицу и столбец а что дальше делать не знаю.

Есть ряд картинок-миниатюр thumb_pic001.jpg до thumb_pic360.jpg также ряд картинок для полного изображения pic001.jpg до pic360.jpg

Не знаю как создать формулу для обновления столбца

```
UPDATE INTO jshopping_products (product_thumb_image, product_name_image)
VALUES (NULL, NULL)
```

Вот как можно выкрутиться? Помогите - проект горит :(